# JQuery datepicker popup em branco

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

Meu projeto é em .NET MVC 4 e estou tendo problema pra chamar o datepicker. Ele é aplicado mas o popup fica pequeno acima do campo e em branco. Quero usa-lo nesse campo:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataDesligamento, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 10, onkeydown = "formatar(this,'##/##/####',event)", onblur = "javascript:valida_data(this);" })
```

No Layout chamado pela View onde está o campo que quero o datepicker faço as seguintes chamadas do Bundles no Head:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ieLt9")   
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/maskedinput")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datepicker")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cpfl")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Acredito que não é isso, pois o datepicker é aplicado e se abrir o console consigo ver que tem dados nele, os dias, meses, anos, mas não são mostrados.

No navegador ao abrir o console, os seguintes scripts são adicionados:

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/select.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/core.pp.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/core.init.pp.js"></script>
```

Na view, no final do arquivo adiciono o datepicker no campo com a linha:

```
aplicarDatePicker('DataDesligamento');
```

Segue a função JavaScript que aplica o datepicker:

```
function aplicarDatePicker(campo) {
    $('#' + campo).datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        language: 'pt-BR',
        autoclose: true
    });
}
```

Estou fazendo algo errado? Por que o datepicker não mostra o conteúdo no popup?

Comment: Aqui `{ @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 10, onkeydown = "formatar(this,'##/##/####',event)", onblur = "javascript:valida_data(this);" })` não faltou você incluir o `id`? Ou seja, `{ id="DataDesligamento", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 10, onkeydown = "formatar(this,'##/##/####',event)", onblur = "javascript:valida_data(this);" })`

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104633/how-to-add-date-picker-bootstrap-3-on-mvc-5-project-using-the-razor-engine)

Comment: Já fiz esse teste antes @Marconi, o ID é gerado exatamente com o mesmo nome do campo que foi usado da Model: "model.DataDesligamento".
Adicionei o ID dele como DataDesligamento2 e chamei dessa forma na função e nada. Estou verificando o link que me passou.

Comment: @George segue o exemplo e ajudei guilherme de outro tópico (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144056/localizar-jquery-datetimepicker-para-pt-br/144103#144103), e tenho vários exemplos se puder e ajudo.

Comment: @Marconi, a única diferença no link que você me mandou é a forma que o datepicker é iniciado. No exemplo ele é iniciado por todos campos com a classe datepicker, adicionei aquela função e coloquei o campo com class='datepicker', ele é iniciado, mas com o mesmo erro.

Comment: @KingRider, meu código parece seguir esses exemplos. E como informei, o datepicker é gerado e até aparece o popup, mas ele fica pequeno e em branco.
Se eu foi no div do datepicker no console do navegador todas as informações estão lá.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui arrumar. Na verdade só mudei a versão do meu jQuery e BootStrap para a mesma que eu tinha em outro projeto que já usava datepicker e funcionou. A versão que coloquei foi a 2.2.3, mas não sei o motivo pelo qual não funcionou com a outra.

Comment: Um recomendado de utilizar 1.9.1, e não pegue mais nova versão por motivo beta acima 2.x. Espera sair versão 3.x e pode utilizar 2.x, a comunidade jquery developer disse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudei a versão do meu jQuery e BootStrap para a mesma que eu tinha em outro projeto que já usava datepicker e funcionou. A versão que coloquei foi a 2.2.3.

Observação: atentar para o comentário do @KingRider que indica o uso da versão 1.9.1 já que 2.x ainda está em beta.